# Hi, I am trying to write a reverse cipher code in C++. I am struggling to get started and could use some guidance?

Tags: c++, encryption

The cipher should take in a string inputted by the user and then spit out the encrypted code.

So if the string is ABCD then the encryption is ZYXW.

But I am struggling to figure how to start writing the function. I want to use a function and then call it in the main function when i need it! Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry my code wasn't complete enough to include in the question. So I don't think it would have been helpful.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can I create a function that will take the letter A and exchange it with Z to encrypt a phrase. @awesomeyi

Comment: @awesomeyi I am not sure if I need like a for loop or if there is something that uses the alphabet in C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    char a[100];
    cout<<"Enter A String :";
    cin>>a;

    //Your Function Calling Should Be this
    //Supposing all characters are uppercase

    int st = 65 , et = 90;
    char b[100];
    for(int i=0;a[i]!='\0';i++){
        b[i] = et - (a[i] - 65);
    }
    cout<<"\nYour Answer :"<<b;

    return 0;
}
```

**This will work for you**

Comment: Could you explain this a bit? Like what each part does @bhaveshkumar

Comment: As per your question you want that the Character get coded in string as the occurrence of it in alphabets but in **REVERSE**  order.

Comment: So, I set a beginning reference st =65 as 'A' = 65 (ASCII Code) and et =90 as 'Z' = 90 (ASCII) code .  Now I simply count it occurrence number , subtracted it from et to get its occurrence from REVERSE alphabets

Comment: and how do you make it work with lowercase?

Comment: Oh wow that is very interesting okay i see

Comment: for lower case , first you need to detect it as a character is Upper or Lower , then 'a' = 97 and 'z' = 122 . Just write the code for Lowercase too

Comment: and use an if statement? @bhaveshkumar

Comment: yes use if statement to select reference values for upper case and lower case

Comment: what is the purpose of the char b[100]?

Comment: I just select it for your better understanding. YOU can replace the characters of a[100] itself :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
char convert(char c) {
    return 'Z' - (c - 'A');
}
```

Use it like this:

```
std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), convert);
```

`s` is the string you want to convert.

[Demo](http://ideone.com/jou315)

Comment: will this work for all letters of the alphabet? also like how does it work? Sorry i am a beginner @awesomeyi

Comment: @agenise1 It calls the convert function on each letter of the string

Comment: so c is just a random variable?

Comment: and if I wanted to do a string then I would just run it through a for loop i guess?

Comment: @agenise1 No, that's what `std::transform` does. You can look at the demo.

Comment: @agenise1: Don't worry about a string until you can use the `convert` function to convert one character. Once you've mastered that you fan write a `for` loop to convert a string, and once you've mastered that you can look into `std::transform`. If you skip steps you'll just wind up back here asking for more help.

Comment: so you don't suggest this solution @Beta ?

Comment: @agenise1: I *do* suggest it, but I advise you to absorb it in small steps.